# Does Twitter and Facebook has spam tweets and posts ? Can I get any example dataset for finding spam?

Tags: machine-learning

Can we find the spam tweets and posts in twitter and facebook?

If yes, How to Identify them.Is there any labelled dataset available as spam and non-spam for spam detection of tweets and posts of twitter,facebook?

what algorithm is used for detection of spam for Japanese & Chinese languages?

Comment: On Twitter it's a bigger challenge to find non-spam tweets.

Comment: Dilip, did you find a labelled spam tweets collection?

Comment: no i did not got any tweet collection.I will let you know if I found any @Adam Smith

Answer (score 1):

First on methods and techniques: there are a lot of language-independent spam detection algorithms. The main task is feature engineering: one need to construct features, that will detect behavioral differences:

- temporal features (posting hour or minute entropy/autoregression, or even more complicated patterns),
- social media profile characteristics,
- other data, that can be gathered through network API (user's client id, activity patterns, friends attributes, etc).

Here is a kind of "classical" paper on Twitter bot detection: [Who is Tweeting on Twitter: Human, Bot, or Cyborg?](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~hnw/paper/acsac10.pdf). It's already 6 years old, but could be a good starting point. Bots are being detected through their posting activity patterns.

Also you can use texts not even trying to "understand" (or parse) them. Just try shingle-based methods, locality-sensitive hashes (LSH). I advise to use [Nilsimsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilsimsa_Hash), but only because that is the only LSH, I used myself. And AFAIK, initially it was built exactly for spam detection. But you can try to search for any other.

And on the datasets: I don't know publicly available Facebook and Twitter spam datasets, but here is a dataset with YouTube comments, hope it will be usefull:
[Network Analysis of Recurring YouTube Spam Campaigns](http://www.icwsm.org/2013/datasets/datasets/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge amount fo spam tweets in my twitter data collected last year during the election. I have trained a spam classifier using the algorithm, features and training corpus linked below, and included it in my data pipeline. I have tested several clustering algorithms before but my results were not good enough..

Not sure about Chinese or Japanese, but my assumption is only the text preprocessing would be different (e.g. different tokenisation method) and it would not effect the user features which showed the highest performance in the paper (unless Asian spammers spam much differently)

[Link to its paper](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/71344/)

[Link to its slides](http://www.slideshare.net/azubiaga/microposts2015-social-spam-detection-on-twitter)

Comment: The trained data was derived from two separated datasets originally created by the authors of "Seven months with the devils: A long-term study of content polluters on twitter" and "Die free or live hard? empirical evaluation and new design for fighting evolving twitter spammers" (both are cited in the linked paper). You may contact them for using their original spammer datasets or their agreement of using the modified ham/spam datasets. I will share the training data with you after this.